# Array mapping in php

Tags: php

I having two arrays say,

```
$array1 = array("code" => "E0089",
                "desc" => "some description");

$array2 = array("code" => "Code",
                "desc" => "Description");
```

resultant array should be,

```
$result = array("Code" => "E0089",
                "Description" => "some description");
```

In short, I want to map two arrays and create third array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short and simple: [array_combine()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

just use it like this:

```
$result = array_combine($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: Very nice but I think the OP actually wanted to map keys and values instead of relying on position in the array

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are already in right order:

```
$result = array_combine($array2, $array1);
```

Otherwise, you will need to do some looping:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array2 as $key => $val)
  $result[$val] = $array1[$key];
```

Comment: Might want to do some checking for `array_key_exists($key, $array1)`

Comment: @Phil, I don't disagree. Left out for the sake of brevity. Got to leave something for the OP to do. ;)